# How to make the return value of a function user input-able in python

Tags: python, math

I am currently working on an integral calculator to turn in as a part of a project. It works perfectly with the exception that I have no idea how to make the function to be integrated as defined by a user. This is how I've defined the function:

```
def func(x):
    return math.sin(x**2)+x*2+2
```

Can any of you think of a way to allow the user to input a function? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What format do you want them to end it in? python code? clicking a webpage? something in the middle?

Comment: @ChrisCharles python code

Comment: @Meh You should mark this thread answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to recommend this but have a look at [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

```
import math

def func(maths_expression, x):
    return eval(maths_expression)


> print func("math.sin(x**2)+x*2+2", 17)
35.973478979714244
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine

Comment: Because of things like this: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Hmm , Good point but in his case, i bet it's for personal or just safe use only. It though can delete some files but i don't think it can do a serious damage without SU privileges?

Comment: @UbdusSamad I would consider deleting personal files serious damage.

Answer (score 2):

Mr Charles' answer is good. As an alternative you might be interested in this though, which uses the sympy module in a similar way.

```
from sympy import *

def func(str, x_value):
    expr = sympify(str)
    var('x')
    return N(expr.subs(x,x_value))

str = 'sin(x**2)+x*2+2'

print (func(str, 5))
```

The user would not have to indicate that the sin function comes from the math module using this approach.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen sympy before. Thanks